# Use triggers to send emails based on time submitted by user

Tags: google-apps-script

I have users subscribing to a mail service using google forms and they indicate how often they would like to receive an email, the value is recorded on a cell(ex.: every 1h, 2h ...).

I would like to loop through each user email and send a message based on the time they chose. Is there a way to do it with triggers?
Here is what I got so far:

```
function sendMail(){  

  for (i=2;i<=lastEmailRow;i++){
    var currEmail = recipients.getRange(i, 2).getValue(); 
    var currentTrigger = recipients.getRange(i, 3).getValue(); //how often
    currentTrigger = currentTrigger.split(" ")[1];

    MailApp.sendEmail(currEmail, "myEmail@sample.com", "Your Daily Mail",
                      { htmlBody: HTML});
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you already know how to look through each user email and send a message etc. without using triggers? If so, please add a [mcve].

Comment: Hey Rubén, long time no see:). edited and added sample script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your script is working fine (I'm not sure as `lastEmailRow` isn't defined on the question code) you have to make some design decisions, like if you will be using only one function or you will be using multiple functions, one for each frequency.

Depending on the above decision, then you could

- create one time-driven trigger that runs very often, let say every hour
- create several time-driven triggers, each with it's own settings.

In any case, you should include some conditions to control to whom send the email.

Comment: Looks like option one is the most feasible although one would have to keep track of conditions and reset them after the trigger executes. Not sure how Option 2 can be effectively implemented. I was hoping there was a way to build triggers so they would know to whom to send mails but I think they were not designed for such task.